# How to pull what endpoints are still using old DNS?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, internal-dns

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 box that served as our DNS server for some time. I built a new one awhile back and we've been haphazardly switching over to the new one. Is there a way to see what endpoints might still be requesting resolutions from the old DNS server? I'd like to turn that box off.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start a packet capture on the old box with [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) with a filter like:

```
dns and ip.dst==ip_of_your_server or dns and ip.src==ip_of_your_server
```

Comment: I figured I might have to go down that road, I just thought there might be a log or something that would tell me that info.

Comment: @SquishemQuick You can install a audit tool, from MS (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn800669%28v=ws.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) but in my opinion it's simplier to run a wireshark portable edition

Answer (score 1):

Lots of direct logging in Windows DNS:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776361(v=ws.10).aspx

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759581(v=ws.10).aspx